# View Pager tabs in middle of fragment

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, swipeview

How do i implement these tabs, the same as in Google plus profile page?

I think I can't use ActionBar tabs as they are clinged to ActionBar. I want the tabs to be below an image like in this image. Also i want these tabs to be fixed. I want three tabs and all three tabs should be visible on screen - as the android fixed tabs plus swipe layout which uses Action Bar tabs though.

[image: Google Plus Profile]

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Jake Wharton's excellent [Android ViewPagerIndicator library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).

[This sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/simple_tabs.xml) gives you what you are after.

Comment: dont know why this was downvoted because it is exactly what the asker was looking for

Answer (score 0):

i have been looking for something like that, but the closest solution i have found is this:

[Google+ profile like scrolling Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823671/google-profile-like-scrolling-effect)

Hope it helps.